# Wrong value in NSNumber, CFNumberType not defined

Tags: objective-c, core-data, int, nsnumber

All,

I have created a datamodel with 3 field:
- beingPlayed type int16
- position type int16
- playedBy type int16

I have generated a class for it.
**Tile.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * beingPlayed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * playedBy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * position;
```

**Tile.m**

```
@dynamic beingPlayed;
@dynamic playedBy;
@dynamic position;
```

I would assume that all 3 variables are NSNumbers and have the type int16 (CFNumberType =  kCFNumberSInt16Type).

When I create the Tile object, I set all parameters to 0 with`[NSNumber numberwithint:0]`

But when I want to set another value for this object, the type of beingPlayed is not set and so the value is not correct.

I have used:

```
self.beingPlayed = self.playedBy = self.position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:175];
```

**Result:**
position = 175 
playedBy = 175 
beingPlayed = -81

I have used:

```
self.playedBy = self.position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:175];
self.beingPlayed = self.position;
```

**Result:**
position = 175 
playedBy = 175 
beingPlayed = -81

When I debug, I see that:
- position has type kCFNumberSInt16Type
- playedBy has type kCFNumberSInt32Type
- beingPlayed has **NO** type....

What is going on here? Where can I set the type or where is the type set?
My issue is that it's now a normal int which can only contain values < 127, but I have set the type in the datamodel to int16....

Edit:

Additional code from OP from comments:

```
Tile *newTile = [NSEntityDescription 
   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tile" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
newTile.playedBy = @(129); 
newTile.position = @(129); 
newTile.beingPlayed = @(129); 
[context save:&error];
```

> Logging: playedBy = -127, position = 129 and beingPlayed = 129

Comment: Try NSNumber * myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[tmpId longLongValue]];

Comment: Apparently you are checking something completely different. Assigning pointers does not copy the underlying objects. `self.playedBy = self.position` means that those two properties point to the **very same object** in memory. They cannot *possibly* have different types (or whatever attributes they have).

Comment: Try not using `NSNumber` at all; you only need it when storing numbers in a collection class and is just an overhead everywhere else.

Comment: Are these Core Data NSManagedObject subclasses?

Comment: @Mundi: I am using Core Data NSManagedObject subclasses yes.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: if they are pointing to the same object, how come they have different types and when I do "self.beingPlayed = self.position" they have different values?

Comment: My first guess is that you need to spell/capitalize "beingPlayed" the same everywhere you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to understand: the generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses use *objects* for all numbers rather than *primitives*. It is also possible to use primitives, but there are some advantages to leaving things the way the Xcode editor creates them.

In short you need to understand that an object in C is just a pointer to this object. So the **value** of this pointer is irrelevant for you. The SDK provides obvious methods to wrap and unwrap `NSNumber` objects.

```
// set
position = @3994;

// get
NSInteger p1 = position.integerValue;
int       p2 = position.intValue;
BOOL      p3 = position.boolValue;

// modify
position = @(position.integerValue + 1);  

// compare
position.integerValue == position2.integerVaue // true if equal
```

Your chained assignments don't work because of the different meaning of `=` when dealing with objects vs. values.

```
NSNumber *x, *y;
x = @1; // assign value to x
y = x;  // y points to x
```

Also, make sure that you are not overriding any getters or setters that could potentially also change the result.

Comment: Hi @Mundi, thanx for the explanation. I understand the concept of objects and pointers. So now I have tested `beingPlayed = @(175)` but then the value is again -81. When I test `self.beingPlayed = [NSNumber numberWithInt:175];` the value is also -81. When I use `CFNumberType numberTypeBP = CFNumberGetType((CFNumberRef)self.beingPlayed);`, (after assignment of the value) I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error....

Comment: It is possible that you are not reading the value correctly, or that you are altering it before reading it.

Comment: Even before I save the object in the context, the data is stored wrong in memory.. `    Tile *newTile = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tile" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newTile.beingPlayed = @(129);` => value is -127

Comment: You are probably still chain-assigning. Please post the exact code you are running for setting and reading (logging) these values, reporting the results as printed in your log statements.

Comment: Tile *newTile = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tile" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newTile.playedBy = @(129);
    newTile.position = @(129);
    newTile.beingPlayed = @(129);
    
    [context save:&error]; Logging: playedBy = -127, position = 129 and beingPlayed = 129

Comment: You should add additional code to the original question, not in the comments, where it is unreadable. Please do 2 things: report the data type of the attributes of your `Tile` entity from the model editor; post (in your question) exactly where and how you log.

Comment: I added screenshots of the code and logging. 4 cases. 2 phones (4S and 5S) and 2 OS types (7.1 and 8.3). I have tried everything.. so you would be a lifesaver...

Comment: Did you override the setter of `column` or `row`? Also, it is possible your model file is corrupted. Try deleting the entity and creating it from scratch. Delete the app from the device/simulator before testing.

Comment: No, I did not override any setters or getters. What do you mean by a "corrupted model file"? Is there any way to check? And is the recreation of the entity enough? I can't delete the whole datamodel, because I have live app users already...

Comment: This is very strange indeed. Maybe you could post a repo somewhere with a test project that replicates the issue? I am willing to look at this, but in view of my effort so far, you should at least upvote this answer.

Comment: Hi @Mundi. I am very grateful for your help! It seems that I have a method isBeingPlayed which returns a BOOL, but this is also the syntax for a KVC method. I missed this... :S Hopefully this will be the solution.. will test it tonight. And I will certainly upvote your effort!

Comment: So I was right with my guess about getters (`isBeingPlayed` is a getter). I will add it to the answer and you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The

> "Also, make sure that you are not overriding any getters or setters
>   that could potentially also change the result."

did the trick! I had a method (BOOL)isBeingPlayed which is also part of the KVC implementation and therefor one of the setters/getters... It slipped my mind.

And because a BOOL is also an int in basic, the type was converted to an int instead of the int16....

Thank you all for your help!